# CSS grid does not fit its parent div's height

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

I built a CSS grid layout with a header, a sider and some scrollable content.

I'm trying to test that layout in a container `div` where I'm setting the `width` and `height`.

The layout responds well to the container's `width`, but not to the `height`, why is that and is there a way to fix it?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px; /* How can I set the height? */
}
.page {
  width: 100%;  
  display: grid;  
  grid-template-rows: 55px calc(100vh - 55px); /* height limitation on second row */
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav header"
    "nav content";
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: grey;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: auto; /* overflow condition on parent */
}

article {
  height: 1000px; /* height set on child; triggers scroll */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="nav">Side nav</div>
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="content">
      <article>
        <!-- new section for content -->
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>A lot of content, simulated by .article height: 1000px</p>

      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set an *explicit height* for the *grid container* and then remove `calc` from `grid-template-rows` and make it `1fr` for the second row.

So you can set `height: 100%` for `page` (so it *inherits* the height of `container`) and use `grid-template-rows: 55px 1fr` (the second row now *expands* to fit the remaining height). See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px; /* How can I set the height? */
}
.page {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; /* added */ 
  display: grid;  
  grid-template-rows: 55px 1fr; /* changed */
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav header"
    "nav content";
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: grey;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: auto; /* overflow condition on parent */
}

article {
  height: 1000px; /* height set on child; triggers scroll */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="nav">Side nav</div>
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="content">
      <article>
        <!-- new section for content -->
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>A lot of content, simulated by .article height: 1000px</p>

      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The `fr` unit was a much better choice indeed, thank you! Is that always a better choice to use `fr` instead of `auto`? I'm wondering if I should also write: `grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;`